# In AEM how can I get project environment into my sling model

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I need to use the environment in my sling model (dev|prod etc, not runmode such as author|publish). How can I inject it into my core model?

Is there any service for this ?

Answer (score 2):

> dev|prod etc, not runmode such as author|publish

`author` and `publish` are among the *fixed* run modes but run modes in general can be used to tell `dev` from `prod` (or similar kinds of environments) as well.

Usually, when AEM environments need to be told apart, e.g. dev vs prod, it *is* realised through [custom run modes](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/deploying/configuring/configure-runmodes.html#customized-run-modes). While AEM as a Cloud Service places some limitations on just how much you can customise, the case you mention is still covered OOTB. Among other things, it [can be used to manage environment-specific OSGi config](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/deploying/configuring-osgi.html#runmode-resolution).

An on-premise/hosted deployment gives you even more flexibility. I've always used customized run modes for this kind of purpose.

One thing to note is that it does raise an eyebrow that you need to programmatically check the run mode in a Sling Model. I'm not sure what you're implementing but if a piece of functionality is dependent on the environment, I'd rather handle it via alternative OSGi configuration assigned to a given run mode. I think it's generally easier to add another configuration as a `sling:OsgiConfig` node when required, as opposed to adjusting conditional logic in a Java class that only recognises a predetermined set of environments.

Provided that you have a set of run modes like this, you could inject `SlingSettingsService` into your model and read the run modes this way. Or you could write an OSGi service to encapsulate whatever logic you need. Such a service would start up with the configuration relevant to a given environment and you could inject it directly into your Sling model, knowing the values it returns are the ones you need.